# Invoke object method regardless of parameter type

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, .net-4.0

I am using a DynamicObject to wrap an internal object and mask generics, however when I try to invoke certain methods on the internal object they require typed paramaters, however I am treating all paramaters as the type Object so the invoke fails.

Code:

```
public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            try
            {
                result = mInternalObject.GetType().InvokeMember(binder.Name, (BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public), null, mInternalObject, args);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
            }
        }
```

So basically, I am wondering how to make it ignore the paramater types and invoke the method with the object anyway, any sugestions?

Comment: You mention "certain" methods fail.  Can you give specific examples of methods that work and methods that don't work?

Comment: for example Add([ObjectType] object) fails when I pass it an object because it is expecting some type. By fails I mean throws an exception that the object does not contain the method at runtime.

Comment: @Alex Hope O'Connor: Sounds like you are not expecting expected behavior :)

Comment: @leppie pretty much, but I got it working using your snippet, I am still getting my head around the DynamicObject and reflection.

Comment: @Alex Hope O'Connor: It may seem daunting at first, but Reflection is quite trivial in most cases. Generics does make it tricky though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want something along the lines of (psuedo code, very simplified):

```
var mem = internalObject.GetType().GetMember(binder.Name);
if (mem.IsGenericDefinition)
  mem = mem.MakeGeneric(Array.Convert(args, x => x.GetType()));
var result = mem.Invoke(null, internalObject, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reflection, since you are using dynamic, you can use [really late binding](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding) from the open source [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) project. It's faster than reflection and will work on more kinds of objects (such as other dynamic objects) and can infer generics while alternatively letting you specify as well, making everything much simpler.